# Use TypeScript interface for runtime validation in/of JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.2

I can create a TypeScript interface like so which will help with static typing:

```
interface IFoo {
   bar: string,
   baz: boolean
}
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to convert this information to JS and use it to do *runtime* validation as well? Otherwise I'd likely have to keep track of this info in two different places which is no fun.

Anyone know if this is possible somehow?

What it might look like is

```
const ifoo = {
     bar: 'String',
     baz: 'Boolean'
}
```

and then I could use an object like that to do runtime validation.

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript will not be transpiled to JavaScript, since it does not have anything similar. TypeScript is mostly used while writing your code to catch errors before running it.

Comment: As @Arg0n said, interfaces aren't meant for runtime. That's what's so nice about typescript, you get compile time safety without the runtime overhead. If you need some sort of validation of inputs at runtime then there are enough libraries for that, for example: [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/)

Comment: I see you both and I think it would be nice if TS gave you the option to use some of the data structures for runtime validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! The module [ts-interface-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-interface-builder) automatically converts interfaces defined in a TypeScript file into descriptors similar to what you suggest, namely:

```
import * as t from "ts-interface-checker";
export const IFoo = t.iface([], {
  "bar": "string",
  "baz": "boolean",
});
```

It works in conjunction with [ts-interface-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-interface-checker) (distributed as a separate npm module) which uses these descriptors to do runtime validation with informative error messages.

Comment: Nice answer, but note that this package does not support generics.